# Firebase/Firestore Not Returning All Results

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I have multiple queries going on to different places. I have not been able to find any documentation on the matter but it appears multiple queries start to interfere with each other.

My problem is, I call a collection query and it returns all the data, as expected. Then when I make a change and call it again (using .take(1)), the results are not the whole collection.

Here is the query I am having the trouble with:

```
this.fireStore.collection('marker_joins', ref => ref.where('marker_id', '==', this.markerID).orderBy('join_date', 'asc')).snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe(res => {
console.log(res);
});
```

It appears if I remove a subscription to another collection, the take(1) works as intended.

Is there any reason I would be seeing this behavior?

Thanks,

Troy

Comment: `take(1)` is supposed to stop the Observable from listening to changes, maybe this is your issue ?

Comment: I only want it to pull results when the user clicks a button due to multiple other users potentially making changes to the collection, I don't have a need to listen to all the changes. Maybe, this isn't best practice?

Comment: That's what I thought, in this case you need to recreate the subscription and not use the same one. With `take(1)`, the observable won't emit anymore values. But [it seems to be a good practice](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/456), just be sure not to use the same subscription for the next request !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow that last bit. Right now, I have the take(1) inside a function and call the function each time the button is clicked. That's not the way to go? Why would it work if I kill off another query subscription that I have?

Comment: Because the first subscription has already ended when you wrote `take(1)`. The observable stops emitting values, meaning the observer doesn't get new values. If you create a new observable, you start emitting a new value, and the observer can receive this new value.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I am looking into that route.

Comment: I've tried creating a new observable by 

`Observable.create(observer => { 
FIRESTORE REQUEST HERE
});` 

and I am left with the same result.

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz with that ? Mock your service with random data, change the data, and reproduce the issue. If I have something to play with, I'll be able to produce a solution for you.

Comment: Oh and by the way, did you try removing the snapshotChanges call ? This also  old be your issue

Comment: Oddly enough, it works in StackBlitz with the take(1), it comes back to other queries interfering with the call.

Comment: It only does not work when there are any other active listeners/subscriptions.